# Get specific value from Json array in angularJS with ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

#### Partial Code

```js
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'lastactivities',
  function($scope, $stateParams, lastactivities) {
    var mytoken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');

    lastactivities.send(mytoken).then(function(activities) {
      var activitytab = activities.data;
      $scope.datab = activities.data;
    });
  }
])
```

```html
<ul ng-repeat="item in datab">
  <li ng-repeat="value in item.date track by $index">{{value}}</li>
</ul>
```

#### JSON

```js
{
  "erreur": "",
  "data": [{
    "date": "2016-03-04",
    "activities": [{
      "type": "bank",
      "icon": {
        "type": "lock-3",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": null,
      "title": "MOT DE PASSE MODIFIÉ",
      "description": ""
    }, {
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "document-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "1 400 €",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "backgroundColor": "#97d42e"
      },
      "action": "925",
      "title": "FACTURE",
      "description": "nike - appli mobile"
    }, {
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "user-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": 925,
      "title": "NOUVEAU CLIENT",
      "description": "nike"
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "2016-03-03",
    "activities": [{
      "type": "bank",
      "icon": {
        "type": "lock-3",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": null,
      "title": "MOT DE PASSE MODIFIÉ",
      "description": ""
    }, {
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "document-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "643,44 €",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "backgroundColor": "#f84c74"
      },
      "action": "719",
      "title": "FACTURE EN RETARD",
      "description": "Justine - Facture 2"
    }, {
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "document-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "400 €",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "backgroundColor": "#f84c74"
      },
      "action": "719",
      "title": "FACTURE EN RETARD",
      "description": "Justine - Ma first facture"
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "2016-02-18",
    "activities": [{
      "type": "bank",
      "icon": {
        "type": "lock-3",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": null,
      "title": "MOT DE PASSE MODIFIÉ",
      "description": ""
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "2016-02-08",
    "activities": [{
      "type": "bank",
      "icon": {
        "type": "lock-3",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": null,
      "title": "MOT DE PASSE MODIFIÉ",
      "description": ""
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "2016-02-02",
    "activities": [{
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "document-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "0 €",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "backgroundColor": "#97d42e"
      },
      "action": "724",
      "title": "FACTURE",
      "description": "Test client - F - 00005"
    }, {
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "document-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "0 €",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "backgroundColor": "#97d42e"
      },
      "action": "720",
      "title": "FACTURE",
      "description": "Abus - F - 00004"
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "2016-02-01",
    "activities": [{
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "user-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": 724,
      "title": "NOUVEAU CLIENT",
      "description": "Test client - Scooby"
    }, {
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "document-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "1 500 €",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "backgroundColor": "#97d42e"
      },
      "action": "720",
      "title": "FACTURE",
      "description": "Abus - Fact"
    }, {
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "user-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": 720,
      "title": "NOUVEAU CLIENT",
      "description": "Abus - Busbus"
    }, {
      "type": "document",
      "icon": {
        "type": "download-6",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": null,
      "title": "7 DOCUMENTS DÉPOSÉS",
      "description": "retrait-par-carte-Invalid date.jpg, Document-01-02-2016.jpg, Doss1, Doss2, Document-01-02-2016.jpg, -Invalid date.jpg, retrait-par-carte-01-02-2016.jpg"
    }, {
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "document-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "643,44 €",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "backgroundColor": "#97d42e"
      },
      "action": "719",
      "title": "FACTURE",
      "description": "Justine - Facture 2"
    }, {
      "type": "bank",
      "icon": {
        "type": "lock-3",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": null,
      "title": "MOT DE PASSE MODIFIÉ",
      "description": ""
    }, {
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "document-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "400 €",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "backgroundColor": "#97d42e"
      },
      "action": "719",
      "title": "FACTURE",
      "description": "Justine - Ma first facture"
    }, {
      "type": "client",
      "icon": {
        "type": "user-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": 719,
      "title": "NOUVEAU CLIENT",
      "description": "Justine - Arma"
    }, {
      "type": "bank",
      "icon": {
        "type": "flag-1",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "badge": {
        "text": "",
        "color": "#000000",
        "backgroundColor": "transparent"
      },
      "action": null,
      "title": "BIENVENUE À BORD DE TIIME AE",
      "description": "C'est parti pour 30 jours offerts"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I'm new in `AngularJS` and trying to display only the `date` and the `type` but no luck yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `<ul ng-repeat="item in datab">` and then `<li>{{item.date}}</li>`

Comment: It works well thanks you so much :)

Comment: @user3130401, please post this as an answer so it can be selected as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in datab">
  <li ng-repeat="value in item">
    {{value.date}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/amjck2qq/1/).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams','lastactivities',
 function($scope, $stateParams,lastactivities) {
  var mytoken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  lastactivities.send(mytoken).then(function(activities){

  var activitytab = activities.data;

   var data=[];
for (var i=0;activities.data.length>0,i++)
{
    for(var j=0;activities.data[i].activities.length>0;j++)
    {
        data.push({date: activities.data[i].date, Type: activities.data[i].activities[j].type})
    }
}

  $scope.datab = data;

  });
 }
])
```